# RISC-V - Iterate through a linked list and apply a function to each node

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, linked-list, riscv

Given a very basic linked list in C:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

I want to write the function "map" in RISC-V assembly language. The map function recursively applies a function to change the value at each node in the list. Ex: square all the data in the linked list. Function in C for reference:

```
void map(struct node *head, int (*f)(int))
{
    if (!head) { return; }
    head->value = f(head->value);
    map(head->next,f);
}
```

The test output is as follows: prints the data in linked list, calls map with the function pointer called "square" which will square each value, then calling map again to a function pointer named "decrement" which will decrease each value by 1.

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 
80 63 48 35 24 15 8 3 0 -1
```

Here is my RISC-V code that I am running in Venus, however I am having an issue with line 76 when I try and call the function passed into map.

```
.globl map

.text
main:
    jal ra, create_default_list
    add s0, a0, x0 # a0 (and now s0) is the head of node list

    # Print the list
    add a0, s0, x0
    jal ra, print_list
    # Print a newline
    jal ra, print_newline

    # === Calling `map(head, &square)` ===
    # Load function arguments
    add a0, s0, x0 # Loads the address of the first node into a0

    # Load the address of the "square" function into a1 (hint: check out "la" on the green sheet)
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    la a1, square


    # Issue the call to map
    jal ra, map

    # Print the squared list
    add a0, s0, x0
    jal ra, print_list
    jal ra, print_newline

    # === Calling `map(head, &decrement)` ===
    # Because our `map` function modifies the list in-place, the decrement takes place after
    # the square does

    # Load function arguments
    add a0, s0, x0 # Loads the address of the first node into a0
    
    # Load the address of the "decrement" function into a1 (should be very similar to before)
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###


    # Issue the call to map
    jal ra, map

    # Print decremented list
    add a0, s0, x0
    jal ra, print_list
    jal ra, print_newline

    addi a0, x0, 10
    ecall # Terminate the program

map:
    # Prologue: Make space on the stack and back-up registers
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    addi sp, sp, -8
    sw ra, 4(sp)
    sw a0, 0(sp)

    beq a0, x0, done # If we were given a null pointer (address 0), we're done.

    add s0, a0, x0 # Save address of this node in s0
    add s1, a1, x0 # Save address of function in s1

    # Remember that each node is 8 bytes long: 4 for the value followed by 4 for the pointer to next.
    # What does this tell you about how you access the value and how you access the pointer to next?

    # Load the value of the current node into a0
    # THINK: Why a0?
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    lw a0, 0(s0)

    # Call the function in question on that value. DO NOT use a label (be prepared to answer why).
    # Hint: Where do we keep track of the function to call? Recall the parameters of "map".
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    jalr ra, 0(a1)

    # Store the returned value back into the node
    # Where can you assume the returned value is?
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    sw a0 0(s0)

    # Load the address of the next node into a0
    # The address of the next node is an attribute of the current node.
    # Think about how structs are organized in memory.
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    lw t0 4(s0)
    mv a0 t0

    # Put the address of the function back into a1 to prepare for the recursion
    # THINK: why a1? What about a0?
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    mv a1 s1

    # Recurse
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    jal ra, map
    lw ra, 4(sp)
    lw s0, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 8
    jr ra

done:
    # Epilogue: Restore register values and free space from the stack
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    addi sp, sp, -8

    jr ra # Return to caller

# === Definition of the "square" function ===
square:
    mul a0, a0, a0
    jr ra

# === Definition of the "decrement" function ===
decrement:
    addi a0, a0, -1
    jr ra

# === Helper functions ===
# You don't need to understand these, but reading them may be useful

create_default_list:
    addi sp, sp, -12
    sw ra, 0(sp)
    sw s0, 4(sp)
    sw s1, 8(sp)
    li s0, 0            # Pointer to the last node we handled
    li s1, 0            # Number of nodes handled
loop:                   # do...
    li a0, 8
    jal ra, malloc      #     Allocate memory for the next node
    sw s1, 0(a0)        #     node->value = i
    sw s0, 4(a0)        #     node->next = last
    add s0, a0, x0      #     last = node
    addi s1, s1, 1      #     i++
    addi t0, x0, 10
    bne s1, t0, loop    # ... while i!= 10
    lw ra, 0(sp)
    lw s0, 4(sp)
    lw s1, 8(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 12
    jr ra

print_list:
    bne a0, x0, print_me_and_recurse
    jr ra               # Nothing to print
print_me_and_recurse:
    add t0, a0, x0      # t0 gets current node address
    lw a1, 0(t0)        # a1 gets value in current node
    addi a0, x0, 1      # Prepare for print integer ecall
    ecall
    addi a1, x0, ' '    # a0 gets address of string containing space
    addi a0, x0, 11     # Prepare for print char syscall
    ecall
    lw a0, 4(t0)        # a0 gets address of next node
    jal x0, print_list  # Recurse. The value of ra hasn't been changed.

print_newline:
    addi a1, x0, '\n'   # Load in ascii code for newline
    addi a0, x0, 11
    ecall
    jr ra

malloc:
    addi a1, a0, 0
    addi a0, x0, 9
    ecall
    jr ra
```

Comment: Does the RISC-V assembly function *have* to be recursive?  It's tail-recursion, much easier to just implement it as a jump, not a call/ret.  Then you'd just want a 2 call-preserved registers and somewhere to stash your return address, instead of needing an amount of stack space that scales with the length of the list!

Comment: @PeterCordes it has to follow the blueprint laid out by the comments, so yes it has to be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
start_msg:  .asciiz "List before: "
end_msg:    .asciiz "List after: "

.text
main:   
    jal ra, create_default_list
    add s0, a0, x0  # $v0 = $s0 is head of node list

    #print the list
    add a0, s0, x0
    jal ra, print_list

    # print a newline
    jal ra, print_newline

    # load your args
    add a0, s0, x0  # load the address of the first node into $a0

    # load the address of the function in question into $a1 (check out la)
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    la a1,square

    # issue the call to map
    jal ra, map

    #print the list
    add a0, s0, x0
    jal ra, print_list

    addi a0, x0, 10
    ecall #Terminate the program

map:
    # Prologue: Make space on the stack and back-up registers
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    
    addi sp, sp, -12
    sw  ra, 0(sp)
    sw  s0, 4(sp)
    sw  s1, 8(sp)
    
    beq a0, x0, done    # If we were given a null pointer (address 0), we're done.

    add s0, a0, x0  # Save address of this node in s0
    add s1, a1, x0  # Save address of function in s1

    # Remember that each node is 8 bytes long: 4 for the value followed by 4 for the pointer to next.
    # What does this tell you about how you access the value and how you access the pointer to next?

    # load the value of the current node into a0
    # THINK: why a0?
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    lw a0 ,0(s0)
    # Call the function in question on that value. DO NOT use a label (be prepared to answer why).
    # What function? Recall the parameters of "map"
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    jalr s1 
    # store the returned value back into the node
    # Where can you assume the returned value is?
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    sw a0, 0(s0)
    # Load the address of the next node into a0
    # The Address of the next node is an attribute of the current node.
    # Think about how structs are organized in memory.
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    lw a0, 4(s0)
    # Put the address of the function back into a1 to prepare for the recursion
    # THINK: why a1? What about a0?
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    add a1, s1, x0
    # recurse
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    jal ra map

done:
    # Epilogue: Restore register values and free space from the stack
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    addi sp, sp, 12
    lw  ra, 0(sp)
    lw  s0, 4(sp)
    lw  s1, 8(sp)
    jr ra # Return to caller

square:
    mul a0 ,a0, a0
    jr ra

create_default_list:
    addi sp, sp, -12
    sw  ra, 0(sp)
    sw  s0, 4(sp)
    sw  s1, 8(sp)
    li  s0, 0       # pointer to the last node we handled
    li  s1, 0       # number of nodes handled
loop:   #do...
    li  a0, 8
    jal ra, malloc      # get memory for the next node
    sw  s1, 0(a0)   # node->value = i
    sw  s0, 4(a0)   # node->next = last
    add s0, a0, x0  # last = node
    addi    s1, s1, 1   # i++
    addi t0, x0, 10
    bne s1, t0, loop    # ... while i!= 10
    lw  ra, 0(sp)
    lw  s0, 4(sp)
    lw  s1, 8(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 12
    jr ra

print_list:
    bne a0, x0, printMeAndRecurse
    jr ra       # nothing to print
printMeAndRecurse:
    add t0, a0, x0  # t0 gets current node address
    lw  a1, 0(t0)   # a1 gets value in current node
    addi a0, x0, 1      # prepare for print integer ecall
    ecall
    addi    a1, x0, ' '     # a0 gets address of string containing space
    addi    a0, x0, 11      # prepare for print string syscall
    ecall
    lw  a0, 4(t0)   # a0 gets address of next node
    jal x0, print_list  # recurse. We don't have to use jal because we already have where we want to return to in ra

print_newline:
    addi    a1, x0, '\n' # Load in ascii code for newline
    addi    a0, x0, 11
    ecall
    jr  ra

malloc:
    addi    a1, a0, 0
    addi    a0, x0 9
    ecall
    jr  ra
```

Comment: What's different between this code and the code in the question? [Edit] the answer to include some text explaining what the problem is, and how to fix it. Use a _small_ code snippet to show what the changes should be, so we don't have to search or copy/paste/diff to find it.